# Manage missing images in Catalyst/Nginx

Tags: perl, nginx, catalyst

in my app there are a lot of pictures that can be missing or lost. A lot of them.
In the Catalyst debugger I can see that they are shown as 404, with a full description of the error.
I am using Nginx, so... if they are static files in the static directory, aren't they supposed to be managed by Nginx instead of Catalyst?
And second: can it be a better approach to test in Catalyst if the picture file exists or not before send it to the template?
There will be more nonexistent pictures that existent ones.

Thanks:Migue

Comment: You neglect to mention any detail, please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8648033/edit) to improve it. What do you mean with "missing"/"lost"? Describe precisely the steps you take, what you observe, and what you really expect to happen. Add Catalyst code/nginx configuration so one can reproduce the problem. http://sscce.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure nginx to handle your static files, instead of passing the requests to Catalyst. For example, if you put all your static files (images, Javascript, css, etc.) in root/static/, your nginx configuration should include:

```
location /static {
    alias /home/user/MyApp/root/static/;
    expires 30d;
}
```

Then you can return a specific image when it is not found:

```
location /static/images {
     root /home/user/MyApp/root/static/images;
     error_page  404 /not_found.gif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie in nginx, and it seems  a very clean approach.

Comment: My first question about the errors in the debuger is a nonsense question. The debuger, obviously is the output of Catalyst test server. Nginx does not play in it.